# Hello World OpenGL program: "glEnableVertexAttribArray was not declared it this scope"

Tags: opengl, freeglut

It's getting frustrating. I've been trying to get a simple hello world type program to run, but it just isn't happening.

I'm using Windows 7 and my graphics card does support the newer OpenGL stuff.
Writing in C with freeglut, and I am compiling with MinGW and Code::Blocks.
In the linker I have freeglut, opengl32 and glu32.
I keep the freeglut stuff in the freeglut folder that is located in my MinGW folder, so under search directories in my build settings I have "C:\MinGW\freeglut\include" for the compiler and "C:\MinGW\freeglut\lib" for the linker.

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>

void NIAppIdle(void);
void NIAppDisplay(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Setup windwing
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("HELLO WORLD");

    // Define GLUT callbacks
    glutIdleFunc(NIAppIdle);
    glutDisplayFunc(NIAppDisplay);

    // Enter render loop
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}

void NIAppIdle(void)
{
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void NIAppDisplay(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    float geometry[] =
    {
        -0.5f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.5f, -5.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
         0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f
    };
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, 0, 0, geometry);
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

The problem is with the "glEnableVertexAttribArray" and "glVertexAttribPointer" functions.
The compiler says that they are "not declared it this scope".

Program can run without those lines, so I guess OpenGL is linked properly, but I simply can't use those functions for some reason, and I know they are a part of OpenGL.
Is it something to do with the version of OpenGL I have or something?

Anyway, it is my first time learning OpenGL, I've probably done something horribly wrong, so I'm asking for somebody to help me. I'm sorry if this post seems a bit crappy, this is also my first time posting in this site. Also I'm sorry for my grammar, English isn't my first language.

Comment: Where did you get this "Hello World" program from?

Comment: http://www.eng.utah.edu/~cs5600/schedule.html    Lecture 15 - Hardware Acceleration, the video

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can only get to glEnableVertexAttribArray by manually loading the function pointer for it. If all you want to do is create a simple hello world program, I'd recommend you use [GLEW](http://glew.sourceforge.net/) to handle that for you.

Comment: It's not an extension, but you do have to [manually load the function pointers](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Load_OpenGL_Functions).

Comment: I tried adding GLEW to my project. I've put the glew folder with it's include and lib, inside of my MinGW folder and put glew32 in my link libraries. Then I added "C:\MinGW\glew-1.7.0\include" and "C:\MinGW\glew-1.7.0\bin" paths in the search directories. Finally I included <GL/glew.h> and put glewInit() under my glutInit(). Now there's a different error: "undefined reference to `__imp____glewInit', undefined reference to `__imp____glEnableVertexAttribArray', undefined reference to `__imp____glVertexAttribPointer'.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how MinGW links, but that's basically telling you that you didn't link to glew correctly. Which glew32 did you link to, and how are you linking to it?

Comment: Here are the screenshots of the build settigns of the project in Code::Blocks: [linker](http://puu.sh/AguQ), [include](http://puu.sh/Agv7), [lib](http://puu.sh/Agvj).  And here's how my MinGW folder looks like: [folders](http://puu.sh/Agxd). I'm not sure if that is even the best way to do it. Maybe I should try cramming all the files in one "include" folder and one "lib" folder that are in MinGW, but that would look rather messy.

Comment: Well I tried it myself and I can't get it to work. I'm guessing it's because the glew binaries are built with microsoft's compiler. However I did get it to work by statically linking to glew. Link to glew32s instead, and add "#define GLEW_STATIC" before you #include GL/glew.h

Comment: I just tried that, and it still doesn't work. :( I get the same errors.

Comment: In code::blocks go to "Settings", "Compiler and Debugger", and under the tab "Other Settings" change "Compiler logging" to "Full command line." Then build, and tell me the output from the Build Log tab

Comment: Here it is: [http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bnaK8Qfg](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=bnaK8Qfg)

Comment: For whatever reason it works perfectly for me... other than updating MinGW or Code::Blocks, I'm out of ideas. :(

Comment: If you're desperate, you could try manually loading the function pointers as Nicol mentioned in the first comment

Comment: Same as you, MinGW with Code::Blocks

Comment: Hm.. I just tried to compile a different program I made few weeks ago that I was sure works, and now it doesn't. And I know I reinstalled MinGW in the meantime, so it might just be there is something wrong with the installation. I'll try to reinstall it and I'll report back.

Comment: If you want here's my Code::Blocks project and everything, including the lib and dll files http://www.2shared.com/file/gAqyB2NM/glew_test.html

Comment: I reinstalled the MinGW, and everything is the same. The weird thing is that the other program I was talking about started working a few minutes after I installed, and I did't change a thing. Anyway, I've tried to run your program and I get missing MSVCR110.dll error. I guess that is Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime, and I have it installed.  I tried to reinstall it but I still get the error. Also notice that you are using cpp, and I am using c, maybe that's the difference.

Comment: Shoot, I probably shouldn't have used the beta Visual Studio to build freeglut. Try this http://www.2shared.com/file/tilkgrur/glew_test.html

Comment: However, the fact that you got the MSVCR110.dll error means that it compiled and linked correctly, so I think this should work!

Comment: Yep, that works. Not really sure why. Here are codeblocks project files for comparison: [mine](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EW5VeWPx) and [yours](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=tL9tRTUZ). Can't really tell what's wrong.

Comment: I found the problem. I noticed that mine glew32s.lib is 1,31MB and yours is 1,22MB, and figured out I downloaded 64-bit GLEW binary, thinking that I must get it because my OS is 64-bit. But now I figure that Code::Blocks isn't, so it was a dumb thing to do. I downloaded the 32-bit and now it works, I don't even have to use the static one. Anyway thanks a lot for your time. You've really helped me out. I wish I could do more than just say thanks.